# Mating a round surface with a flat surface

Tags: adhesive

I have a small flat surface (~80mm x 80mm) that needs to adhere to a round surface (radius = 100mm). Does anyone know how to mate the two surfaces together using tape to give a good enough bond?

Any thought appreciated.

EDIT: The part with the flat surface (~250g) is supposed to be hung on the round part (a lamp shade). Both parts are plastic. I'm hoping to avoid causing damage to either part. The whole assembly will be kept indoor.

Comment: You need to tell us what you mean by "good enough."  What would be "good enough" if the object was going to spend the next 100 years in a display case in a museum is not the same as if you plan to send it into low earth orbit! The materials of the two parts are also very relevant.

Comment: @alephzero Sure. I've updated my post now.

Comment: Unfortunately, plastic is extremely broad when it comes to adhesives. On one end, HDPE (high density polyethylene) is extremely hard to adhere things to. Its only been in the last few years that glues for HDPE have even come on the market. (Well, fluoropolymers are even worse, but thats unlikely). If its PVC though, thats a fairly trivial job to bond well. Any guess what kind of plastic it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more about your requirements here are some options:

"Permanent" options:
Try a two-part epoxy designated for plastics. Using sandpaper, like 120 grit, to roughen the surfaces helps with adhesion.

Alternatively, maybe a double-sided foam tape would work. Specifically VHB tape.

If you're using acrylic, you could use the special acrylic glue solvent which makes a strong bond.

"Non-permanent" options:
 zip ties/cable ties or a hose clamp to hold the parts together